# Equivalent java date to php date function when calling jar

Tags: java, php, date

I am trying to find equivalent Date function for php

My java code date object is set as show below :

```
 Date m_travelDate = new Date();
```

I tried in php

```
  $date = new DateTime();
  echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

But when setting the date to java function by php (by calling the jar ) gets error :

```
  $CartObject = new java("myjava.javaclass.Cart", "272929"); 
  $date = new DateTime();
  $m_travelDate=$date->getTimestamp();//$timestamp = time(); //$date->getTimestamp();
  $CartObject->setTravelDate($m_travelDate);
```

setTravelDate((o:Date)[o:Long]). Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch VM: 1.8.0_65@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-10 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ

Comment: I recommend that in Java you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I don’t know which types you can transfer between Java and PHP. If you end up having to pass a text string, use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: It looks like it expects a long. Or maybe that's what you're providing. I have never used the [tag:php-java-bridge]. But I note it's XML based.